# Command to replace string and value in particular file on Ubuntu

Tags: string, sed, ubuntu-14.04

Team, I have file under /etc/login.defs in my Ubuntu machine.

This file has below line

UMASK       022

I wanted to replace with

UMASK       027

So could  someone help me to change the same, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an editor like vi or emacs or gedit or kate or ....? Since it is under /etc you might need `sudo`

Comment: i have sudo permission, However i need to replace through sed commands. as later i need to call the sed command in my script.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting help and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to write a better question... you'll also have to show your efforts to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -Ei 's/(UMASK[^0]+02)2/\17/g' /etc/login.defs
```

Use `\1` to print the matched regex pattern between the parentheses. And substitute the last digit from 2 to 7.

Comment: Oh thank you very much...! its working perfectly. Thanks a lot.